# ng-model value not show in <select>

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, sqlite

I have my html as:

```html
<label class="item item-input item-stacked-label" ng-repeat="nl in normativas">
    <select ng-model="nl.idResultado">
        <option value="1">OK</option>
        <option value="2">NOT</option>
        <option value="3"> MAYBE </option> 
    </select>
</label>
<button ng-click="guardarNormativas()"> Guardar</button>
```

#### Create View

When `$scope.normativas = [];`

I can select value for `nl.idResultado`, I save the content of `$scope.normativas` in my database, where each `nl.idResultado` saves as `1`, `2` or `3`. This is all good.

#### Edit View

When I rescue this `$scope.normativas` and render in the same HTML with `nl.idResultado = 1` (for example), `<select>` does not display `"OK"` as a default value.

The value `nl.idResultado` is received correctly from the sqlite database.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the numeric value 1 does not equal the string value "1". Select elements have a string value by default and there are a couple ways around this. As Aleksey pointed out you can use `ng-value`, but another way of setting up selects with non-string values is to use `ng-options`. Sometimes it's easier to just use `ng-value`, but I'll put this here to give you an alternative.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', ($scope) => {
    $scope.optionValues = [{
      value: 1,
      text: 'OK'
    }, {
      value: 2,
      text: 'NOT'
    }, {
      value: 3,
      text: 'MAYBE'
    }];
    $scope.selectedValue = 1;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <select ng-model="selectedValue" 
          ng-options="option.value as option.text for option in optionValues">
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: OP's `<select>` is repeated multiple times in `<label ng-repeat=...`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Understood. That doesn't change the fact that you can use `ng-options`, it just means the `ng-model` would be different than my [greatly simplified] example.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `ng-value` instead of `value`. It will bind it to scope correctly for you. Here is a demo:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.normativas = [
    {"y":1},
    {"y":2},
    {"y":3},
    {"y":1}
  ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <label ng-repeat="x in normativas track by $index">
    <select ng-model="x.y">
        <option ng-value="1">OK</option>
        <option ng-value="2">NOT</option>
        <option ng-value="3"> MAYBE </option> 
    </select>
  </label>

  <pre>{{normativas | json}}</pre>

</div>
```